# Error when signing into R Studio on Google Cloud VM: Unable to connect to service

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I want to run Rstudio on a VM through Google Cloud Platform. Everything seems to work except when I sign in to RStudio I receive an 'RStudio Initialization Error': "Unable to connect to service". My username and password are correct as if they're wrong it tells me so.

I created the instance using RStudio on my laptop. I've tried adding a rule in Google Cloud Platform to allow all access to the IP address but that did not work.

```
#My Code

library(googleComputeEngineR)

#Setup ------------
project <- "r-bench"
zone <- "europe-west1-b"
account_key <- "gcs-key.json"

Sys.setenv(GCE_AUTH_FILE = account_key,
           GCE_DEFAULT_PROJECT_ID = project,
           GCE_DEFAULT_ZONE = zone)

gce_auth()

#Set our default global project
gce_global_project(project)
gce_global_zone(zone)

default_project <- gce_get_project("r-bench")
default_project$name

#Deploy instance
vm <- gce_vm(template = "rstudio",
             name = "rstudio-demo",
             username = "rstudio",
             password = "xxxxxxxx",
             predefined_type = "n1-standard-1")
```

I expect to sign in and use RStudio as normal. Instead, I receive the error I mentioned previously.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken using rstudio is a reserved name and as a username is not allowed.